# Stripe API: How to create a subscription just using lookup key?

Tags: javascript, curl, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a subscription on Stripe by using the `lookup_key` as the initial information.

The API call is made using cURL.

I did not find a way yet to do that without making an additional request to retrieve the `price_id`.

So far, I tried to use the following queries via "v1/subscriptions" but they are invalid:

- "items[0][lookup_key]"
- "items[0][price][lookup_key]"
- "items[0][price_lookup_key]"

It would be nice to have the most direct way to create a subscription using the lookup_key.

How would you achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, that's not supported. You need to retrieve the Price first then use that, or cache the lookup key to current Price ID relationship in your own systems.

Comment: Thank you! Would you retrieve the prices using search(/v1/prices/search) or list(/v1/prices)?

Comment: Either one, but I would suggest the List API, given it supports `lookup_key` filtering and does not have the availability and rate limit caveats of Search. https://stripe.com/docs/search#data-freshness

Comment: Thank you, Nolan. Meanwhile, I figured out how to use the `lookup_key` with the List API. That way I was finally able to create a subscription.